# How to add end tag using jQuery or any other way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this tag.

```
<p>
    <suggestion id=\"e87c7ef9bc864f08d8d93417eab96dbae:user-2\" suggestion-type=\"insertion\" type=\"start\">
    </suggestion>You should try first.

</p>
```

Now I want to add:

```
<suggestion id=\"e87c7ef9bc864f08d8d93417eab96dbae:user-2\" suggestion-type=\"insertion\" type=\"end\">
```

after `You should try first` text.

I am using this method  `p.append()` but it is giving as text not tag.

Comment: Can you please show me a documentation about the `<suggestion>` tag? Cannot find any...

Comment: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/collaboration/track-changes/track-changes-integration.html

Comment: Without seeing more code or undertanding what you want to achieve, it looks like you want to add attributes to spoof HTML. I think you should try doing this a different way. Look into DOM manipulation.

Comment: Ah, so the `<suggestion>` tag is being than converted into a `<span>`

Comment: If you put the "You should try first" text inside a `<span></span>` tag you can add a new element after it with `$.append(...)`

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kc1s43ue/) what you're trying to do?

Comment: I guess because in your code you don't create a `suggestion` element and append it as text. Try something like this `p.append($('<suggestion></suggestion>'));`

Answer (score 0):

You have to `append` a DOMNode else it's appended as text.
I.e.:

```js
let suggestion = document.createElement("suggestion");
suggestion.setAttribute("id", "e87c7ef9bc864f08d8d93417eab96dbae:user-2");
suggestion.setAttribute("suggestion-type", "insertion");
suggestion.setAttribute("type", "end");
document.getElementById('bar').append(suggestion);
```

```html
<p id='bar'>
<suggestion id=\"e87c7ef9bc864f08d8d93417eab96dbae:user-2\" suggestion-type=\"insertion\" type=\"start\">
</suggestion>You should try first.

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').append("<suggestion id=\"e87c7ef9bc864f08d8d93417eab96dbae:user-2\" suggestion-type=\"insertion\" type=\"end\">");
```

Did exactly what I think you want. Starting with

```
<p>
    <suggestion id="e87c7ef9bc864f08d8d93417eab96dbae:user-2" suggestion-type="insertion" type="start">
    </suggestion>You should try first.

</p>
```

I ended with

```
<p>
    <suggestion id="e87c7ef9bc864f08d8d93417eab96dbae:user-2" suggestion-type="insertion" type="start">
    </suggestion>You should try first.
<suggestion id="e87c7ef9bc864f08d8d93417eab96dbae:user-2" suggestion-type="insertion" type="end">
</p>
```